# How to output a view field only on the first row?

Tags: views, entities, notifications

I have a view where notification messages are listed and on the top a simple field that shows a value from the user's "notifications" field.

The problem is that it shows on each row, whereas I just want it to output in the first row.

How can this be done excluding css and jQuery?

This is the view code:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'user_activity';
$view->description = 'Show all existing messages.';
$view->tag = 'Message';
$view->base_table = 'message';
$view->human_name = 'User activity';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Defaults */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['perm'] = 'administer message types';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '30';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* No results behavior: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['content'] = 'No messages created yet.';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['format'] = 'filtered_html';
/* Relationship: Message: User uid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['id'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['field'] = 'user';
/* Field: User: Notifications */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_notifications']['id'] = 'field_notifications';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_notifications']['table'] = 'field_data_field_notifications';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_notifications']['field'] = 'field_notifications';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_notifications']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_notifications']['group_type'] = 'count_distinct';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_notifications']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_notifications']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_notifications']['settings'] = array(
  'thousand_separator' => '',
  'decimal_separator' => '.',
  'scale' => '0',
  'prefix_suffix' => 1,
);
/* Field: Message: Render message (Get text) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['id'] = 'message_render';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['field'] = 'message_render';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['label'] = 'Text';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = 'User';
/* Field: Message: Timestamp */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['date_format'] = 'time ago';
/* Sort criterion: Message: Timestamp */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Message: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['exposed'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['operator_id'] = 'type_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['label'] = 'Message type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['operator'] = 'type_op';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['expose']['identifier'] = 'type';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'admin/content/message';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Messages';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['description'] = 'A list of all messages.';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['name'] = 'management';

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block_1');
$handler->display->display_options['block_description'] = 'User activity';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include the field you want to have displayed at the top included in the fields of the View, but then excluded from display, you can use it as a replacement token in a global text area in the Header of the View, eg:

[image]

will include the node title in the View, but won't print it in the rows, and:

[image]

will put it at the top of the View when it is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Might it be an option to use two views - create the first one so that it includes the notification field, then the second view to list all the other entries other than the first,  without that field?