# How to check the first item/content on Drupal View

Tags: views, 8

I'm currently using Drupal Views and I'm trying to figure how to check the first item/content on the view. On a twig template I could write

```
{% for items in related_content.entity.field_content_items %}

    {% if loop.first %}

    first element

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

I tried writing the same condition within the view using `{% if loop.first %}` but it doesn't work. Is there similar code to achieve this within Drupal Views Custom Text

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to print other stuff of [the loop variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable), maybe `{{ loop.index }}`, did this work? You then could if-request this. As far as I remember `loop.index` worked fine in Drupal.

Next thing you can try is to [iterate over the keys](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys-and-values) and if-request the key for your logic. Pretty much the same as `loop.index`.

```
{% for key, items in related_content.entity.field_content_items %}
  {% if key == 0 %}
```

Last resort would be to target `related_content.entity.field_content_items[0]` directly.

But I think the first two suggestions should give you at least one opportunity to do what you want.

---

Thanks for the clarification. Views custom text only. OK, in that case consider to use 2 views (or just 2 displays of the same view) as outlined here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/104608. Then you'd attach the first view (or display) - which is limited to display only 1 row - before your second view (there must be an attachment option somewhere) and your second view then should be configured to have an offset of 1.

Comment: Just to clarify I'm using Drupal 8 views `custom text`. I believe the looping syntax you have provided is for `twig templates` https://imgur.com/a/JUOIOKB

Comment: @clestcruz – In that case consider to use 2 views  (or just 2 displays of the same view) as outlined here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/104608. Then you'd attach the first view (or display) - which is limited to display only 1 row - before your second view (there must be an attachment option somewhere) and you second view then has an offset of 1.

Comment: I see, there is no syntax in detecting the first content/item.

Comment: @clestcruz – Maybe no. But there's the Views attachment before/after thing. And there might be some Views header/footer thing if I remember it right. So, depending on what exactly you want to output there, these might become pretty handy :)